# Collections sort generics types java

Tags: java, generics, collections, comparable

I was looking for an answer to my question for so long. I found loads of similar topics but I still do not know what to do.

I have a class where I want to store objects in sorted ArrayList.

For instance, I created this class:

```
public class Kwadrat implements Comparable<Kwadrat> {

    private int a;

    public Kwadrat(int a){
        this.a = a;
    }

    public int get_size(){
        return a*a;
    }

    public int compareTo(Kwadrat b){
        if(b.get_size() > get_size()){
            return -1;
        }
        if(b.get_size() < get_size()){
            return 1;
        }
        return 0;
    }
}
```

And here is my `Sort` class:

```
public class Sort <T> {
    ArrayList<T> arraylist;

    public Sort(){
        arraylist = new ArrayList<T>();
    }


    public void add(T element){

        arraylist.add(element);

       Collections.sort(arraylist);



    }
}
```

`Collections.sort(arraylist);` still tells me that "no instance(s) of type variable(s) `T` exists so that `T conforms to Comparable<? super T>`".

Comment: If you need to store the elements sorted, I would suggest using a `TreeSet` instead of `ArrayList` which has to be sorted manually each time an element is inserted.

Comment: I agree with @Filkolev. Do you really need an ArrayList (indexed access)?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your `Sort` class currently has no bounds on its type parameter `T`, so it could be any type, even a type that isn't `Comparable`.  It would accept `Object`, which is not `Comparable`.  Because there is no bounds, and because the compiler sees that there are bounds on what can be passed to the single-arg [`Collections.sort` method](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Collections.html#sort-java.util.List-), there is your compiler error.

You should create the same bounds on `T` that `Collections.sort` expects.

```
public class Sort <T extends Comparable<T>> {
```

Or even better:

```
public class Sort <T extends Comparable<? super T>> {
```

Answer (score 3):

Change `T` to `T extends Comparable<T>` in the `public class Sort <T> {` line, because the method requires `<T extends Comparable<? super T>>` parameter.